# How does the at&t ARO data analyzer tool work without the data collector APK in the simulator?

Tags: android, performance, monitoring, simulator

The at&t ARO tool comprises of two components.

1. Data collector
2. Data analyzer

To monitor app performance in an android device, we need to install the datacollector.apk in the device and then interface it with the data analyzer. But to monitor an app in the android emulator, the apk(data collector) is not needed, and I need to know how it happens.

I went through the code for the data analyzer, but i was unable to find how it interfaces with the simulator.

if anyone of you can find how it happens by going through the code, it would be a great help.

source : https://github.com/attdevsupport/ARO

Answer (score 1):

The analyser uses the DatacollectorBridge class (in com.att.aro.com package) to talk to the device or emulator. Roughly:
- when connected to a device it runs the apk,
- when connected to an emulator, it runs shell commands through adb.
Hope this helps.